# In Spring Boot Test, how do I map a temporary folder to a configuration property?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-test, temporary-files

I want to do a self-cleaning test

In my situation, I have one of the components depend on a directory

```java
public class FileRepositoryManagerImpl implements ....

    @Value("${acme.fileRepository.basePath}")
    private File basePath; 
}
```

The value is defined in the `application.yml` file, and in DEV it points to a directory under `build`.

This is not the worst idea, because `gradle clean` will eventually clean up the mess the tests create.

But, really, what I would like to achieve here, is to make sure that every test runs in an isolated temporary directory that is cleaned up after execution.

I know that JUnit has a tool for the temporary directories. But once I have defined that directory in the scope of JUnit 4, how do I tell Spring to use that temporary directory?

I **tried** the inner class unsuccessfully:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SecurityBeanOverrideConfiguration.class, App.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public abstract class AbstractFileRepositoryManagerIntTests {

    private final static TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @ClassRule
    public static TemporaryFolder getTemporaryFolder()
    {
        return temporaryFolder;
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme")
    static class Configuration
    {

        public FileRepository getFileRepository()
        {
            return new FileRepository();
        }

        static class FileRepository
        {

            public File basePath() throws Exception
            {
                return temporaryFolder.newFolder("fileRepositoryBaseDir");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about *tinkering* with the `Environment`, but what should be the correct way to inject properties programmatically in a Spring Boot test?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of at least four different approaches to your problem. All with their own advantages and disadvantages.

**Approach 1: ReflectionTestUtils**

You are using `@Value` annotation on a private instance property (please, don't to that anymore!). Hence, you can not change `acme.fileRepository.basePath` on the fly without reflection.

```java
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FileRepositoryApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileRepositoryApp.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class FileRepository {

        @Value("${acme.fileRepository.basePath}")
        private File basePath;

        public File getBasePath() {
            return basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `basePath` after each test with `ReflectionTestUtils.setField`. Because we are using Spring's [TestExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html), that gets initialized before Junit rules are initialized, we are forced to manage the temporary folder in `beforeTestExecution` and `afterTestMethod`.

```java
package demo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import java.io.IOException;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileRepositoryApp.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = FileRepositoryAppTest.SetBasePath.class, mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class FileRepositoryAppTest {

    private static TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Autowired
    private FileRepositoryApp.FileRepository fileRepository;

    @Test
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(fileRepository.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), fileRepository.getBasePath());
    }

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(fileRepository.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), fileRepository.getBasePath());
    }

    static class SetBasePath implements TestExecutionListener {

        @Override
        public void beforeTestExecution(TestContext testContext) throws IOException {
            temporaryFolder.create();
            if (testContext.hasApplicationContext()) {
                FileRepositoryApp.FileRepository bean = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(FileRepositoryApp.FileRepository.class);
                ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bean, "basePath", temporaryFolder.getRoot());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) {
            temporaryFolder.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 2: Configuration properties**

Introduce a configuration properties class for your application configuration. It gives you [type safety](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) for free and we don't rely on reflection anymore.

```java
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class FileRepository {

        private final FileRepositoryProperties fileRepositoryProperties;

        public FileRepository(FileRepositoryProperties fileRepositoryProperties) {
            this.fileRepositoryProperties = fileRepositoryProperties;
        }

        public File getBasePath() {
            return fileRepositoryProperties.getBasePath();
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme.file-repository")
    public class FileRepositoryProperties {

        private File basePath;

        public File getBasePath() {
            return basePath;
        }

        public void setBasePath(File basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }

}
```

Because we are using Spring's [TestExecutionListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html), that gets initialized before Junit rules are initialized, we are forced to manage the temporary folder in `beforeTestExecution` and `afterTestMethod`.

```java
package demo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.IOException;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = FileRepositoryWithPropertiesTest.SetBasePath.class, mergeMode = MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class FileRepositoryWithPropertiesTest {

    private static TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Autowired
    private FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp.FileRepository bean;

    @Test
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(bean.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), bean.getBasePath());
    }

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(bean.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), bean.getBasePath());
    }

    static class SetBasePath implements TestExecutionListener {

        @Override
        public void beforeTestExecution(TestContext testContext) throws IOException {
            temporaryFolder.create();
            if (testContext.hasApplicationContext()) {
                FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp.FileRepositoryProperties bean = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(FileRepositoryWithPropertiesApp.FileRepositoryProperties.class);
                bean.setBasePath(temporaryFolder.getRoot());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) {
            temporaryFolder.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Approach 3: Refactor your code (my favorite)**

Extract `basePath` into its own class and hide it behind an api. Now you don't need to poke with your application properties and a temporary folder anymore.

```java
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FileRepositoryWithAbstractionApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileRepositoryWithAbstractionApp.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public class FileRepository {

        private final FileRepositorySource fileRepositorySource;

        public FileRepository(FileRepositorySource fileRepositorySource) {
            this.fileRepositorySource = fileRepositorySource;
        }

        public File getBasePath() {
            return fileRepositorySource.getBasePath();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class FileRepositorySource {

        private final FileRepositoryProperties fileRepositoryProperties;

        public FileRepositorySource(FileRepositoryProperties fileRepositoryProperties) {
            this.fileRepositoryProperties = fileRepositoryProperties;
        }

        // TODO for the sake of brevity no real api here
        public File getBasePath() {
            return fileRepositoryProperties.getBasePath();
        }
    }

    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "acme.file-repository")
    public class FileRepositoryProperties {

        private File basePath;

        public File getBasePath() {
            return basePath;
        }

        public void setBasePath(File basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

We don't need any additional testing facility anymore and we can use `@Rule` on `TemporaryFolder` instead.

```java
package demo;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileRepositoryWithAbstractionApp.class)
public class FileRepositoryWithAbstractionTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @MockBean
    private FileRepositoryWithAbstractionApp.FileRepositorySource fileRepositorySource;

    @Autowired
    private FileRepositoryWithAbstractionApp.FileRepository bean;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(fileRepositorySource.getBasePath()).thenReturn(temporaryFolder.getRoot());
    }

    @Test
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(bean.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), bean.getBasePath());
    }

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println(temporaryFolder.getRoot().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(bean.getBasePath());
        assertEquals(temporaryFolder.getRoot(), bean.getBasePath());
    }

}
```

**Approach 4: TestPropertySource**

Use Spring's [TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) annotation to override properties in a test selectively. Because a Java anntotation can not have a dynamic value, you need to decide beforehand where you want to create your directory and keep in mind your test is bound to a specific operating system due to the used os path separator.

```java
package demo;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static demo.FileRepositoryTestPropertySourceTest.BASE_PATH;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = FileRepositoryApp.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "acme.fileRepository.basePath=" + BASE_PATH)
public class FileRepositoryTestPropertySourceTest {

    static final String BASE_PATH = "/tmp/junit-base-path";

    private Path basePath = Paths.get(BASE_PATH);;

    @Autowired
    private FileRepositoryApp.FileRepository fileRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(basePath);
        Files.createDirectories(basePath);
    }

    @After
    public void after() throws IOException {
        Files.deleteIfExists(basePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(fileRepository.getBasePath());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use JUnit 5.4+ then you can leverage their `@TempDir` that works just fine without manual lifecycle management of the directory. That is you don't need to create and delete it manually, in contrast to `@TemporaryFolder` from JUnit 4.

Here is a working example of how you can achieve your goal:

```java
//Your bean into which you want to inject the property
@Component
public class FileRepositoryManager {
    @Value("${acme.fileRepository.basePath}")
    private File basePath;

    public File getBasePath() {
        return basePath;
    }
}

//Test that uses ApplicationContextInitializer machinery to set the desired properties
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = Initializer.class)
class FileRepositoryManagerTest {
    @TempDir
    static File tempDir;

    @Autowired
    FileRepositoryManager fileRepositoryManager;

    @Test
    void basePathIsSet() {
        assertNotNull(fileRepositoryManager.getBasePath());
    }

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "acme.fileRepository.basePath=" + tempDir
            ).applyTo(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Just in case, one can notice it's not required to implement an `@SpringBootTest`, a `@SpringJUnitConfig` annoted test is enough.